# IF / ELSE Statements in Batch...?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

Hello stackoverflow community! First of all, this is my first post, and I'm not too good with technical terms so excuse any mistakes or things of the sort in this post.

I'm making a text-based adventure game in Batch, and I'm currently working on a small segment of it. For the life of me, I just cannot figure out how to do IF / ELSE statements. I've tried nested conditions, with no success. Here is what I have:

```
echo You step up to the light. Luckily, it's pretty dim,
echo so you're not burning your corneas.
echo:
echo What would you like to do?
echo:
echo 1] Attempt to fix the light
echo 2] Go back to do something else
echo:
set /p decision=I want to...
if "%decision%"=="2" goto restartStartNoLightFix
if "%decision%"=="1" goto 
echo That choice is invalid.
ping localhost -n 4 >nul
goto inspectFlickerLight
```

@echo is off.

I want if "%decision%"=="1" to be followed by checking if the player has the part to fix the light. Nested conditions were a failure, as said, and since this will be a full blown game it seems that using a `goto checkvariable` will crowd up with each decision I use.
Also, decision is a constantly changing variable, if that will affect anything.

I appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "nested conditions were a failure".  `if "%decision%"=="1" if %partcount%" GEQ "1" echo Fixing light`

Comment: I do not see any nested code nor do I see code for checking for the part to fix the light. You also are using GOTO, but there are no labels to go to.

Answer (score 0):

What about checking the variable directly before asking the question?

```bat
Echo=You step up to the light. Luckily, it's pretty dim,
Echo= so you're not burning your corneas.
Echo=
If Defined LightFix (
    Echo=What would you like to do?
    Echo=
    Echo=1] Attempt to fix the light
    Echo=2] Go back to do something else
    Echo=
    Set/P decision=I want to...
    If "!decision!"=="2" GoTo :restartStartNoLightFix
    If "!decision!"=="1" GoTo :inspectFlickerLight
    Echo=That choice is invalid.
    Ping localhost -n 4 >nul
)
```

If the variable, *in this case named **%LightFix%** for demonstration purposes*, hadn't previously been set when the player got the part, then they wouldn't ever see the question.

Depending upon your preference you could write it this way too:

```bat
Echo=You step up to the light. Luckily, it's pretty dim,
Echo= so you're not burning your corneas.
Echo=
If Not Defined LightFix (GoTo :NextBit)
Echo=What would you like to do?
Echo=
Echo=1] Attempt to fix the light
Echo=2] Go back to do something else
Echo=
Set/P decision=I want to...
If "%decision%"=="2" GoTo :restartStartNoLightFix
If "%decision%"=="1" GoTo :inspectFlickerLight
Echo=That choice is invalid.
Ping localhost -n 4 >nul
:NextBit
```

I use = after Echo, *(my personal preference)*, instead of your use of space or colon.

Here is the section from your comments restructured.

```bat
If "%decision%"=="1" (
    If Defined hasPart (
        If "%hasPart%"=="True" (
            GoTo :fixFlickerLight
        ) Else (
            Echo=You need the parts to fix the light!
            Timeout 3 >Nul
            GoTo :inspectFlickerLight
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi @Compo, won't the first example need DelayedExpanion?

Comment: The first example needs indeed delayed environment variable expansion. I use delayed expansion always after `set /p "variable=prompt text"` as a user can enter intentionally or by mistake a string containing for example `"` which results with `if "%decision%"=="2"` in an exit of batch processing because of a syntax error. But `if "!decision!"=="2"` and delayed expansion enabled at top of batch file works even if a user with a German keyboard pressed Shift+2 and typed therefore by mistake `"` instead of `2`.

Comment: @LotPings, I have changed the upper example to delayed expansion format, but have not added the instruction for it because I'd really need to add it in an appropriate location, which I cannot do without seeing the entire code and structure.

Comment: Hi there, @Compo! First of all, thanks for the answer. I probably should've clarified this a bit more - I was more / less looking for a way to use IF ELSE or IF NOT commands. Every time I tried it seemed that the ELSE / IF just plain didn't work, and with a tad bit of research it definitely seemed that option just simply wasn't available. Would it be possible for me to have something like this? (Read next comment)

Comment: `if "%decision%"=="1" (
 if "%hasPart%"=="True" (
 goto fixFlickerLight
 )
 if "%hasPart%"=="False" (
  echo You need the parts to fix the light!
  ping localhost -n 4 >nul
  goto inspectFlickerLight
  )
 )
`
Keep in mind, it doesn't have to exact. Just something like that?
Also it's kind of irritating that it doesn't line break in Stackoverflow comments, but pretend that the code has line breaks to make it organized.

Comment: @Compo I tried the first example of your code, but it seems to either be not registering that hasPart is defined, or it's skipping over that segment of code. Doing this in free time in my school hours, I'll be sure to say what's going on specifically tomorrow. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: @Gl1tchCrashed, I have added a small section at the bottom of my answer to show how I would write what you have in yout last but one comment.